# RDD Persistence in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I have a question about, when a `RDD` is stored in memory.
Lets say I have this code:

```
val dataset = originalDataset
  .flatMap(data => modifyDatasetFormat(data, mappingsInMap))
  .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

So far I have a `RDD` which is stored in memory of each worker node.

Questions:
If I do another transformation or action to this `RDD`, will this persistence stop exist and I should create another one or it doesn't have anything to do with it?

If I change partitions in this `RDD` (e.x hash partitions) will this persistence stop exist and I should create another one or it doesn't have anything to do with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If i do another transformation or action to this rdd, will this persistance stop exist

No.

> If i change partitions in this rdd (e.x hash partitions) will this persistance stop exist

No.

Transformations (including repartitions) can't change existing RDD, and in particular they can't unpersist it. Of course

1. The result of the transformation won't itself be persisted;
2. (Incorrect, as pointed out in Jem Tucker's comment) <s>You need to transform the persisted RDD, not the one you called `persist` on.</s> I.e.

   ```
   val dataset1 = originalDataset.
     flatMap(data => modifyDatasetFormat(data, mappingsInMap))
   dataset1.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
   val dataset3 = dataset1.map(...)
   ```

   will recalculate `dataset1`. Instead you need

   ```
   val dataset2 = dataset1.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
   val dataset3 = dataset2.map(...)
   ```

Comment: So in other words....for every new rdd that is created i have to persist it and unpersist the old one.Is that right?

Comment: I believe your point 2 is incorrect, when you call persist on an rdd the return value is the 'this' reference, so both your examples are in fact effectively the same.

Comment: Lets say you have this: val dataset2 = dataset1.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
val dataset3 = dataset2.foreach(...). If you do a transformation on the dataset2 then you have to persist it and pass it to dataset3. Am i correct?

Comment: You should only need to persist datasets that are used multiple times

Comment: @Nick No. If you had to do this every time, why wouldn't Spark do it automatically? The point of persisting an RDD is to avoid recalculating it; if it's only used for one action or transformation, it wouldn't be recalculated anyway.

Comment: @JemTucker Yes, you are right. I misremembered something there.